# C# encryption specific data different output

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm looking for way of encrypting/decrypting a specific value but with different output every time.

I have a list of users and each has an `UserId` which is a Guid.

```
User1: 00838CED-6926-4632-830F-B8F509BEC0F5

User2: 7DEAAC47-FE88-4943-BFDE-AAC986F65A23

User3: ECBB005F-1E6B-441A-8538-944383D6C0AE
.........
UserN: 479A344E-364D-4DA7-A3F8-99D94301815F
```

Then I want to be able to encrypt these guids in such a way that each time I get a different output. And when I decrypt it it will get me that UserId which is the guid.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add a random string to the end of the GUID each time you encrypt, and strip it off and discard it when you decrypt.

Comment: @RichieHindle: can you describe what you mean?

Comment: I've expanded my comment into an answer.

Comment: FYI, this is called salting.  Do a search for "salting passwords" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a random string to the end of the GUID each time you encrypt, and strip it off and discard it when you decrypt.

To encrypt:

```
# Add a random string to the end of the GUID before encrypting
encrypted = encrypt(guid + ":" + a_random_string)
```

To decrypt:

```
# Strip off and discard the random string after decrypting.
guid = decrypt(encrypted).split(':')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you can create a custom class.Go like this in that class

1.Add an unique string like datetime to the **userid** at the end
2.encrypt the value
3.Store it in dictionary with key as string and encrypted userid as value
4.Reverse the process on decryption.